# Are there any differences between the new and old Titanic version besides 3D?

Tags: 3d, alternate-version, titanic

The newest Hollywood trend seems to be taking old movies like Star Wars and Lion King and rerelease them with an additional third dimension to squeeze the last bit of money out of them.

Now it hit Titanic, which is currently running in the movies in a 3D version.

I was wondering: Are there any changes apart from the 3D effect that have been made to the theatrical version of Titanic, for example

- cuts,
- additional scenes,
- cgi postproduction,
- anything else?

Comment: @atticae I enjoyed the ironic line: 'now it hit Titanic'

Answer (score 35, accepted):

James Cameron has been asked this a few times in the past weeks to the release of the movie, and he has said he did not want to change anything about the movie past adding 3D. However, it seems he admits to making a change while interviewing with a British magazine *Culture*. James Cameron resisted temptation to cut scenes he was no longer happy with when preparing to re-release his blockbuster film Titanic in 3D, [however...]

> Neil deGrasse Tyson, who is one of the U.S.' leading astronomers, sent me quite a snarky email saying that, at that time of year, in that position in the Atlantic in 1912, when Rose is lying on the piece of driftwood and staring up at the stars, that is not the star field she would have seen, and with my reputation as a perfectionist, I should have known that and I should have put the right star field in.
>
> So I said, *"All right, you son of a bitch, send me the right stars for the exact time, 4:20 a.m. on April 15, 1912, and I'll put it in the movie,"* Cameron said. *"So that's the one shot that has been changed."*

Comment: Here was Tyson's opinion on the matter, causing him to contact Cameron - _"There she is looking up. There is only one sky she should have been looking at ... and it was the wrong sky! Worse than that, it was not only the wrong sky; the left-half of the sky was a mirror reflection of the right-half of the sky! It was not only wrong, it was lazy! And I'm thinking, this is wrong."_

Comment: [Here's a clip of Tyson telling the whole story](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8B6jSfRuptY).

Comment: Hah, funny. While watching that video I just realized that Tyson is the same guy shown in the famous ["Watch out we have a bad-ass over here"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/neil-degrasse-tyson-reaction) meme.

Comment: Rofl. Pedantry FTW.

Comment: How could it be 4:20 am? The Titanic hit the iceberg at around 11:45 pm, and then it took a couple of hours for it to sink completely. It's safe to assume that the broken half of the ship (the back half) sank at 2:20 am - since it's explained in the forensic analysis. The rest of the sequence must have happened in the half-hour after the sinking - so till 3 am. How could it have been 4:20 am? Rose looks up at the sky while still lying down on the plank, so we don't have to wait till she's rescued.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the updated starfield, the 3D version of Titanic was opened up to 16:9 from the original 2.35:1 aspect ratio (at least for the Blu-ray disc; I'm not sure if the same was true for its theatrical release).

Additionally, stray strands of hair were removed, presumably to make it easier to separate characters from the background as part of the 3D conversion.  I don't know if there are similar minor tweaks elsewhere in the movie.

Answer (score 3):

He re-rendered the stars in the sky over the sinking ship to make them accurate, as explained in [this Discovery News article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120413035825/http://news.discovery.com/space/neil-degrasse-tyson-tightens-titanic-accuracy-120402.html).

(and widely reported elsewhere).